# Where are the documents for the CordovaInterface and the CordovaWebView?

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, ionic-framework

Over [this link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins), I found some example codes about the Cordova plugin initialize.

```
@Override
public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
    // your init code here
}
```

But I can't find any document about how to use that.

**Update:**

I want to know what the `CordovaInterface` and the `CordovaWebView` can do.

In fact, I trying to make the plugin more interactive with the JS.

Comment: found this https://code.google.com/p/jfx-gap/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jfxgap/api/CordovaWebView.java?r=c3e848ef583ece62766988d715517170b0715b3a

Comment: found this https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java

Comment: what do you want to know? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: cordovaInterface and cordovaWebView are just interfaces for the new webviews that can be used (crosswalk and gecko view), so this new webviews can still use existing plugins. You won't find documentation about them because you shouldn't use them, but you can read the code https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaInterface.java

Comment: Thanks, @jcesarmobile. But why I shouldn't  use them?

Comment: Sorry, I meant you shouldn't modify them, but of course you can use them. To use them, just put this.webView. or this.cordova. and eclipse will show you the available methods you can use